# Verify suspend function with Matchers.anyObject()

Tags: android, junit, mockito, kotlinx.coroutines

I'm attempting to add coroutines to our Android application but I'm hitting a snag with our mocking framework.  My interface has a suspend function like so:

```
interface MyInterface {
  suspend fun makeNetworkCall(id: String?) : Response?
}
```

Here is how I'm attempting to verify the code was executed in my unit test

```
runBlocking {
  verify(myInterface).makeNetworkCall(Matchers.anyObject())
}
```

When I do this I'm getting the following error

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
2 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
-> at     com.myproject.MyTest$testFunction$1.invokeSuspend(MyTest.kt:66)

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
  //incorrect:
  someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
  //correct:
  someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));
```

Is there another way we should verify that the appropriate method is being called when using coroutines?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to write similar test using the code you have provided. Initially, I got same error as yours. However, when I used ***mockito-core v2.23.4***, the tests were passed.

Here are quick steps which you can try:

1. add `testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.23.4"` to the dependencies list in your build.gradle file.
2. Run the tests again, and you should not get similar error.

As `Matchers.anyObject()` is deprecated, I used `ArgumentMatchers.any()`.

Below you can see the client code:

```
data class Response(val message: String)

interface MyInterface {
    suspend fun makeNetworkCall(id: String?) : Response?
}

class Client(val  myInterface: MyInterface) {
    suspend fun doSomething(id: String?) {
        myInterface.makeNetworkCall(id)
    }
}
```

Here is the test code:

```
class ClientTest {
    var myInterface: MyInterface = mock(MyInterface::class.java)

    lateinit var SUT: Client

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        SUT = Client(myInterface)
    }

    @Test
    fun doSomething() = runBlocking<Unit> {
        // Act
        SUT.doSomething("123")
        // Verify
        Mockito.verify(myInterface).makeNetworkCall(ArgumentMatchers.any())
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  For some reason I'm getting the following error while running the example provided: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.internal.progress.ThreadSafeMockingProgress.mockingProgress()Lorg/mockito/internal/progress/MockingProgress;

Comment: Here is the line in the stacktrace that references the code.
at com.myproject.TestingStuff$doSomething$1.invokeSuspend(TestingStuff.kt:37)

Comment: Have you updated mockito to v2.23.4? I tried on both Intellij Idea and Android Studio, but I couldn't get similar error

Comment: Maybe you can try cleaning and rebuilding?

Comment: If you're using any other testing library, the error might be related to that as well.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm trying to go through updating to version 2 of mockito but I'm running into several issues.  Hopefully once I resolve those I can verify that my main issue goes away.

Comment: @DroidT let me know if you need any help

Comment: That did the trick.  I had to migrate to migrate to mockito 2.  It wasn't easy but well worth it.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am facing this problem in Mockito v3.1.0